# SQL to look at multiple conditions and if ANY are invalid, deliver a single 'NotOk' value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question for the SQL Geeks out there.

I'm trying to set a flag on a table if any of the 3 below conditions return a 'N' value. Basically, if any of the 3 conditions are met, then I need to set a flag on a Control table. I can't figure out quite how to do this, because I'd also like to return a Reason that the Control table will be set to 'N'. This worked fine with one condition but with 3 I'm not sure.

Here's the SQL:

```
select Reason, TheCount,Dating_OK_to_Proceed 
from
(
SELECT  'More than 2 Seasons Are Open' as Reason,  COUNT(SEASCLOSED) as TheCount, 
case when COUNT(SEASCLOSED) > 2 then 'N' else 'Y' END as Dating_OK_to_Proceed
FROM dbo.DATING
GROUP BY SEASCLOSED
HAVING (SEASCLOSED = 0)

union all

SELECT  'More than 1 Season has Ordering Switched On'  as Reason,  
COUNT(ORDERON) as TheCount,
case when COUNT(ORDERON) > 1 then 'N' else 'Y' END as Dating_OK_to_Proceed
FROM dbo.DATING
GROUP BY seasclosed, ORDERON
HAVING (ORDERON > 0) and SEASCLOSED = 0

union all

SELECT  'More than 1 Season has Invoicing Switched On'  as Reason,  
COUNT(INVOICEON) as TheCount,
case when COUNT(INVOICEON) > 1 then 'N' else 'Y' END as Dating_OK_to_Proceed
FROM dbo.DATING
GROUP BY seasclosed, INVOICEON
HAVING (INVOICEON > 0) and SEASCLOSED = 0
) as OkGo
```

If all 3 conditions return a Y, instead of 3 rows, I want to return a single row with 'Y'.

But if any of the conditions return a 'N' then I want to return a single row with the corresponding reason and the 'N'.

Is this possible?

Comment: But what if multiple conditions return `N`? What "corresponding reason" should be used?

Comment: And which row do you want to return when all three return `Y`? And when there are multiple `N`s?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really h elp.

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit from learning about the EXISTS() function in SQL Server.   And probably the CASE expression as well.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Tx- good call, I hadn't anticipated that. I'd take the first reason that returned a N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this:

```
with OkGo as
 (
    SELECT  'More than 2 Seasons Are Open' as Reason,  COUNT(SEASCLOSED) as TheCount, 
    case when COUNT(SEASCLOSED) > 2 then 'N' else 'Y' END as Dating_OK_to_Proceed
    FROM dbo.DATING
    GROUP BY SEASCLOSED
    HAVING (SEASCLOSED = 0)

    union all

    SELECT  'More than 1 Season has Ordering Switched On'  as Reason,  
    COUNT(ORDERON) as TheCount,
    case when COUNT(ORDERON) > 1 then 'N' else 'Y' END as Dating_OK_to_Proceed
    FROM dbo.DATING
    GROUP BY seasclosed, ORDERON
    HAVING (ORDERON > 0) and SEASCLOSED = 0

    union all

    SELECT  'More than 1 Season has Invoicing Switched On'  as Reason,  
    COUNT(INVOICEON) as TheCount,
    case when COUNT(INVOICEON) > 1 then 'N' else 'Y' END as Dating_OK_to_Proceed
    FROM dbo.DATING
    GROUP BY seasclosed, INVOICEON
    HAVING (INVOICEON > 0) and SEASCLOSED = 0
 ) 
, RankedReasons as
 ( select Reason, TheCount, Dating_OK_to_Proceed,
      -- if there's any 'N' it will be sorted first and gets rank 1,
      -- otherwise 1 is assigned to the first 'Y'
      row_number()
      over (order by Dating_OK_to_Proceed) as rnk
   from OkGo
 )
select * from RankedReasons
where rnk = 1 --return a single row for 'Y' or one out of multiple 'N's
```

To get all rows with 'N' you just have to add a final

```
   or Dating_OK_to_Proceed = 'N'
```

Comment: This is so perfect. Thanks for helping me get there.